# Spring Boot with JNDI Data Source

Tags: spring, jndi, spring-boot

I have a new Spring Boot web application that I want to connect to a JNDI data source (a MySQL database defined in Tomcat's context.xml).

However when I attempt this, I always get the following exception;

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database url for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported on on the classpath.
```

This is despite my pom.xml containing the MySQL connector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.test</groupId>
<artifactId>twojndi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Two JNDI Data Sources</name>
<description>Two JNDI Data Sources Example</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>org.test.twojndi.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

I have defined my application.properties as follows to use the jndi-name property.

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/twojndi_ds1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

However despite that it seems Spring believes that an in-memory database should be used.

I am able to connect to the MySQL database if I define my application.properties as so

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twojndi_ds1
spring.datasource.username=twojndi
spring.datasource.password=twojndi
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Can anyone help me connect to JNDI with Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring boot 1.1 doesn't support jndi lookups, the upcoming 1.2 does. If you want to do a lookup in 1.1 do it yourself... Also when doing a jndi lookup you shouldn't need a driver as that is all part of the server.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum.  In fact upgrading to 1.2.0.M1 was the answer!

Comment: I would upgrade to M2 as that is a bit newer... Not sure when the final is about to be released (not sure if there is a release calendar for that).

Comment: I tried that M. Deinum.  However I encountered this issue when deploying to a standalone Tomcat: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1733

Comment: I'm now going to try two JNDI data sources.  Not sure if the @EnableAutoConfiguration will configure the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter for both of those or if I can just follow this approach: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources ?

Answer (score 6):

As commented by M. Deinum, JDNI lookup is implemented in Spring Boot 1.2, current version is 1.2.0.M2.

If you want to do it with Spring Boot 1.1, you can define a bean like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName("jdbc/jndidatasource");
    try {
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while retrieving datasource with JNDI name jdbc/jndidatasource", e);
    }
    return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dunni.  I upgraded to Spring Boot 1.2.0.M1 and was able to do it via the spring.datasource.jndi-name property.  Upvoted none-the-less.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked the following configuration, guided by the recipe exposed in this [link](http://vinayshivaswamy.blogspot.com/2014/12/jndi-lookup-in-spring-boot.html), but as they said before the same work with versions of spring boot 1.2 or more

```
public class DomainAndPersistenceJndi {
private JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.INFORMIX);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate...");
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSourcejndi")
public DataSource dataSourcejndi() throws NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    bean.setJndiName("java:jboss/datasources/..." );
    bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryJndi")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryJndi(@Qualifier("dataSourcejndi") DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource( dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(EntidadBase.class.getPackage().getName());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("BaseDSjdni");

    em.afterPropertiesSet();

    return em;      
}
```

}